How to debug mysterious UWP crash?
I'm working on a large UWP application. My customers report that the app occasionally "disappears". They say it usually happens after they've left the app running on their computer for a long time, and may be associated with the computer entering sleep mode.
I cannot easily replicate the problem, but if I run the app in Debug mode from Visual Studio and leave it up overnight, I do find that it has crashed the next day. However it is not a normal crash where Visual Studio shows a crash report and a breakpoint. In fact, I cannot find any kind of crash report anywhere. I checked the CrashDumps folder, I checked Event Viewer, and I checked Reliability Monitor. I also checked App Center since our app is set up to use it.
There's a folder at c:\Program Data\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Report Archive which has a timestamp that corresponds to the time period of the crash, but I cannot open the folder to see what's inside of it, even though I'm logged in as an Admin.
Is there something else I can do to try to find the problem?
Thanks,
Frank

Check the Windows event logs (Control Panel). (It "seems" you did) The machine updates itself; restarts; etc. You need an unhandled exception "handler"; a log; and sometimes I have a health monitor (timer) that reports home (e.g. device not responding).


Is there something else I can do to try to find the problem?

There are some suggestions and I hope that could help.
You could try to use the Application.UnhandledException Event to check if there are an exception can be handled by app code. For example, if the Windows Runtime invokes app code like an event handler, and the app code throws an exception and does not catch it, the exception will propagate back to the Windows Runtime. The Windows Runtime will then fire the UnhandledException event to notify the app of this exception.
Another way is to check the Event Viewer to see the system log which will contains some information as well. Please go to Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Apps -> Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational to check the system log. More information you could refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting#get-diagnostic-information
At last, you could try to integrate your app with Visual Studio App Center. App Center could give analytics for sessions, events and crashes. App Center is scheduled for retirement on March 31, 2025 but currently it is still available.
